# Small post and beam project sanity check

Tags: timber-framing, joinery

I'm planning to build a canoe rack out out of PT 4x4s, post and beam style. The goal is mostly to learn to build something that way.

I've designed it in SketchUp, below. Everything is a 4x4. The pegs are 3/4" in the design but I'm wondering if 5/8" wouldn't be plenty strong enough.

Since I don't have a clue what I'm doing, I hope somebody can tell me what the worst problems are with this design. Thanks! Please let me know if there's any additional information that I can provide.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, how much does your canoe weigh ? That is one BEEFY canoe rack.

Comment: @AlaskaMan I know, it's massive overkill for a canoe rack. I just couldn't think of anything else to build that way.

Comment: Two saw horse's work great.

Comment: For learning to cut mortises?

Comment: You did not state in your question that this was a way for you to learn how to do mortise and tenon joinery. Go for it, If you are going to invest in all that material and time then maybe go for a pergola ?

Comment: I agree with the pergola , but it would need to be anchored. Good skills to know if my grandfather saw me doing it with a chain saw today, he’d probably tan my hide.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Second sentence: "The goal is mostly to learn to build something that way." Check the edit history. A pergola would be a good idea and I did think of building one on our back patio, but it would block the view from the kitchen, and there's no other place where we'd want one. I might do a shed, but I want to do a smaller practice project first.

Comment: Pretty impeccable, design-wise. This might just be me, but I'd use redwood/cedar for two reasons: 1. you can get it dry, where pt is typically at a swamp emc. 2. I'd hate to be around that much pt sawdust. Yep, it'll cost more, but the heirloom canoe rack nature of this would make me think of the upcharge amortized over 40 years.

Answer (score 3):

Can I use your canoe rack to drive my quad up and work on it? 
That is a bit over built but will be rock solid. Make your cuts tight when using pegs everything is a friction fit but you have it well laid out. 
It appears you will be just setting it on the ground so you can move it that would be my justification for the lower horizontal braces. This should hold up fine for whatever size canoe you can hoist up there.
My grandfather always used hard wood pegs, we used fur for the timbers but I only did a few small additions with him to his barn and the hard wood was important but a pain in the back side to cut off on his tree limb ladders.